# Package Maker run pre-install script

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I have to make a installer using package maker, package maker version is Version 3.0.4 (179)
In our package, before installing, we need to run the a script, ( Pre-Install script) , which should check the JAVA Version,
if version is less then 1.6 then it should tell user to take update of JVM and installation should quit without installing the App,

I did following, 
In Distribution, click on pre-install Action and added this script,
Added necessary action what message should show when it failed,

its working fine on my machine, but when i tried to run on other machine which is having JVM1.6 installed,  the package is failing,

after doing lot of investigation, i got following piece of code in **Raw-Editing-mode**

```
<script>
function pm_install_check() {
    if(!(system.run('/Users/amitg/Documents/MacApp/CheckJVMScript.sh') == true)) {
        my.result.title = 'JAVA VM Error ';
        my.result.message = 'JAVA Version should be 1.6 or above, ';
        my.result.type = 'Fatal';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

It means it search on a pre-defined path and it seems its failing due to it didn't get script on that path.

It seems, package is expecting script to be present at that path , or i am doing any mistake while giving path, i checked there, there is no absolute / relative path.

Are there any work-around, for that, googling says , there is preflight script , but i didn't get any documentation for that.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Rohan, Instead of doing it in the Distribution, under contents select your app. The view beside will change to show the package details.

There click on the scripts tab and select the preinstall script that you have created. By doing this the script will be included in your package.

This should help you achieve the task that you are trying to do.